# debian X Xconf resolution xrandr badmatch

Tags: debian, xrandr, resolution

Recently I minimal installed debian squeeze(amd64), when I configs my resolution, unexpected errors came out, I did a lot of searching, but couldn't find a way to figure it out.

1. to install the desktop environment: `apt-get update`, `apt-get install xorg-core xserver-xorg-core gnome-core gdm3`
2. to install graphic grivers `apt-get install build-essential nvidia-kernel-common linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, `./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.64.run`

steps above seems all things is in the correctly way.

3. to set resolution : `cvt 1440 900`, `xrandr --newmode xxx`, `xrandr --addmode VGA-0 xxx`

then I got that error:

> X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
>     Major opcode of failed request:  153 (RANDR).
>     Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode).
>     Serial number of failed request:  29.
>     Current serial number in output stream:  30.

I don't know what information U need, and just list some

graphic card: nvidia gt630.

monitor: phlips 190cw(1440x900, works well on windows)

`xrandr` out put

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1440x900_60.00 (0x29f)  106.5MHz
        h: width  1440 start 1528 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock   55.9KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock   59.9Hz
```

`lshw -c video` out put

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: nVidia Corporation
   vendor: nVidia Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff(prefetchable) memory:f0000000-f1ffffff(prefetchable) ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff(prefetchable)
```

xorg.conf

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     55.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

---

**update**:

I trid to get edid: `apt-get install read-edid`, `sudo get-edid | parse-edid`

but got this error:

```
get-edid: get-edid version 2.0.0

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f00 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
    Function supported
    Call successful

    VBE version 300
    VBE string at 0x11100 "NVIDIA"

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Report DDC capabilities

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
    Function supported
    Call successful

    Monitor and video card combination does not support DDC1 transfers
    Monitor and video card combination does not support DDC2 transfers
    0 seconds per 128 byte EDID block transfer
    Screen is not blanked during DDC transfer

Reading next EDID block

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Read EDID

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x1 cx=0x0
    Function supported
    Call failed

The EDID data should not be trusted as the VBE call failed
Error: output block unchanged
```

---

**update**

I tried to force the resolution to 1440x900 by using `nvidia-settings`, after reboot, resolution changed to 1440X1024(nvidia-settings added a line to xorg.conf `Option "metamodes" "1440x1024 +0+0"`). screen become horizon-scrollable like that:

[image]

I also tried to extract `edid.bin`(by using nvidia-settings) and add `Option "CustomEDID" "DFP-1:/etc/X11/edid.bin"` at `Section "Device"` to xorg.conf. [thanks to the awesome post `Fixing Ugly DVI/HDMI Displays due to EDID bugs on nVidia drivers`](http://analogbit.com/fix_nvidia_edid#comment-7), but unfortunately it doesn't work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do... Did you solve it?

Comment: @AdrianLopez i've gave up.  Just bought an other monitor :)